# Why size of jpg file is bigger than expected?

Tags: python, jpeg

I generate a grayscale image and save it in jpg format.

```
SCENE_WIDTH = 28
SCENE_HEIGHT = 28

# draw random noice
p, n = 0.5, SCENE_WIDTH*SCENE_HEIGHT
scene_noise = np.random.binomial(1, p, n).reshape((SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT))*255
scene_noise = scene_noise.astype(np.uint8)

n = scene_noise
print('%d bytes' % (n.size * n.itemsize)) # 784 bytes

cv2.imwrite('scene_noise.jpg', scene_noise)
print('noise: ', os.path.getsize("scene_noise.jpg")) # 1549 bytes

from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray(scene_noise)
im.save('scene_noise2.jpg')
print('noise2: ', os.path.getsize("scene_noise2.jpg")) # 1017 bytes
```

when I change from:

```
scene_noise = np.random.binomial(1, p, n).reshape((SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT))*255
```

to:

```
scene_noise = np.random.binomial(255, p, n).reshape((SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT))
```

The size of file decrease almost 2 times: ~ 775 bytes.

Can you please explain why JPG file is bigger than the raw version and why the size decreases when I change colors from black and white to full grayscale spectrum?

```
cv2.__version__.split(".") # ['4', '1', '2']
```

Comment: This is not a small investigation you're asking for. The first place I'd start is to determine whether it's a property of the JPEG encoder that's being measured, or the amount of entropy (which is to say, the amount of randomness) in the data; as a matter of course, even an ideal compressor will generate larger output if there's more entropy in the input.

Comment: If-and-only-if it turns out to be a property of the encoder you're measuring, then we get into questions about whether it's *one specific* encoder, which library versions you're linked against and whether the behavior at hand is specific to same, &c.

Comment: I have added opencv version

Comment: (as for greyscale resulting in smaller files -- remember that JPEG is lossy; an ideal implementation tries to throw out details it doesn't think the human eye will see; starker contrasts are thus less likely to be thrown out than small ones).

Comment: The JPEG file is bigger than what you call the raw version because the raw version is a NumPy array. As a result, it does not need to store information other than the integers in each cell of the array.

Comment: I wasn't actually asking for the opencv version, but the libjpeg version that your opencv build is linked against. But determining whether any of this is version-dependent is part of your job as the person making the claim.

Comment: I have added PIL implementation. The size is different but the main issue was reproduced. The size of jpg image is larger than original numpy array.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image? Given that the JPEG is only about 1KB I guess the image must not be very big - in which case the overhead of the JPEG format will hurt. If your image is very big then you should see space savings. As for the size differential, I think @CharlesDuffy is right - as a *lossy* format, a high-contrast image of pure black and white will compress much worse than a low-contrast image of sparkles; the latter can be much better approximated.

Comment: *nod*. JPEG is optimized for compressing real-world images -- things that have *shapes*, and boundaries, and regions within those shapes that only change incrementally. Random data has basically nothing in common with the design target, so poor performance is utterly unsurprising.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you are right, JPEG is lossy and when I restore Numpy array from JPEG file it differs from the original. Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things here:

- can you explain why the JPEG file is bigger than the raw version?

> The size differs because you are not comparing the same things. The first object is a NumPy array, and the second one is a JPEG file. The JPEG file is bigger than the NumPy array (ie. after creating it with OpenCV) because JPEG encoding includes information in the overhead that a NumPy array does not store nor need.

- can you explain why the size decreases when I change colours from black and white to a full grayscale spectrum?

> This is due to JPEG encoding. If you truly want to understand all of what happens, I highly suggest to understand how JPEG encoding works as I will not go into much detail about this (I am in no way a specialist in this topic). Information on this is well documented on [the Wikipedia JPEG article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Encoding). The general idea is that the more contrast you have in your picture, the bigger it will be in terms of size. Here, having a picture in black and white only will force you to always go between 0 and 255, whereas a grayscale picture will not usually see as big a change between adjacent pixels.

Comment: The difference in contrast explains the difference is size. There are some cases where NumPy object is larger than JPEG file.